# how can i call jquery function from another jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i having existing javascript document.in this document I want to call a one fuction,the

Comment: With `var cuboid = new $.Cuboid(config, pos)`, I suppose. Still, as it stands it's quite meaningless per se.

Comment: The same way you call `$.Deferred`.

Comment: it is plugin,i searched over the this,i want to call specifically this function only.

Comment: If you want to create a plugin instead, there's a plenty of tutorials - and the one quite fine to start is right [at the mothership](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/). The key is extending `$.fn` (jQuery prototype) instead of `$` (jQuery) object.

Answer (score 2):

Call like this:

```
var cubo = new $.Cuboid("lala", "lele");
```

And "cubo" value are:

```
$.Cuboid {config: "lala", pos: "lele"}
```

Answer (score 1):

just call like:

`$.Cuboid(config, pos)`

Comment: The way the function is programmed, you'll need the `new` keyword here.

Comment: you are right. we need new here